# Render jsf element only if url is exact path

Tags: jsf

I'm willing to render a link only if i'm on an specific URL and I cant guess what would be the rendered condition:
The link should only be rendered if page im displaying is "datosRegistro.xhtml"

```
 <h:outputLink value="/sede/documentos/ManualOperadorRA.pdf" 
    style='text-decoration:none; color:gray; cursor:pointer' 
    rendered="#{what can I fit in here}">   
    <h:outputLabel value="#{messages['registro.info.manual.usuario']}" />
 </h:outputLink>
```

Comment: why don't you just include the component on the page that is related to the specific url? But as an alternative, there are predefined (implicit) EL 'objects', of which 'request' is one. http://incepttechnologies.blogspot.com/p/jsf-implicit-objects.html

Comment: Oh, totally forgot to mention the fact that this is being included in the footer thats displayed in the whole website. I could create a new footer and only include this fragment in the template, but then i'd have to mantain two different footers. Will have a look at request.

Comment: You can have a define in the (footer) template that is empty for all pages but only populated in this specific page via 'include'. Very common 'usecase'...

Comment: Indeed, i was so stubborn to use rendered didnt even think of using define - insert.

Comment: #{request.requestURI == 'url'}